# GWT IE9 Dev Mode error

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-9, dev-mode

As pictured I see the following error when opening my page in IE9.  I am on GWT 2.3.0 and IE9.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `<set-property>` tag in your `gwt.xml` that restricts the values of the `user.agent` property? This message is generated by `UserAgentAsserter` as a sanity-check when the runtime configuration of the module doesn't line up with the `user.agent` values it was compiled with.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie9" />
```

to your module description (`gwt.xml`).